# How to support multiple UI for a web app

Tags: web-applications

I have this webapp which works fine deployed on JBoss and its targeted for browsers on laptops and desktops. I never had intentions of making this app available on mobile devices.

Now would like to cater to mobile customers as well, hence my question is what are the possible ways in which it can be done.

I thought of :

1. Deploy one more instance of my application with UI for mobiles (Not at all a solution I think)
2. A entry filter to determine the agent and redirect accordingly (Seems OK)

Comment: Why not one UI for all using adaptive or/and responsive layout.  Use Google on these you will get more than engouth referance to make your own opinion...

Comment: That was the direction I was looking...why cant you add that as an answer, I can accept that as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new media query and other new CSS functionality you can use the same pages for any HTML client.

The adaptive (fluid layout) and responisve (layout change base on size) desing is currenlty a hot topic.  Google can give you enought material to chose (and refine) the right solution for your need.